How to hide all hidden files and folders except for the specific hidden file(ex .gitignore) in VS Code
I hide all hidden files by setting **/.* in Files:Exclude.
But I still want to see the .gitignore file.
How can I do it?
Please do not say set unwanted hidden files and folder names in Files:Exclude individually...
I tried to set the unwanted files in files exclude individually but there are too much files and folders to exclude..

Does this answer your question? Can you define a files.include setting like the files.exclude setting?
